# How handle click listener for recyclerView item from contextual action mode?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

[image]

I want to make recyclerview item click like this image.When i selected recyclerview item press long click then contextual action mode is enable.If i select only one item then show edit menu item else not.I want when i click edit menu item then click on recyclerView selected item and do some work.But i can't do it.Please help me some one.I am a new in android development.
Advanced Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I grab some info for you, that might be help for you,

Once setSelectable() is implemented, you can achieve the rest of **CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL** by using a regular **ActionMode.Callback**. Call through to your setSelectable() from within the relevant callback methods:

```
private ActionMode.Callback mDeleteMode = new ActionMode.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
            setSelectable(true);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
            setSelectable(false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) { ... }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) { ... }
    }
```

Then use a long click listener to turn on the action mode:

```
private class CrimeHolder extends SwappingHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

        ...

        public CrimeHolder(View itemView) {
            ...

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            itemView.setLongClickable(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity)getActivity();
            activity.startSupportActionMode(mDeleteMode );
            setSelected(this, true);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Let me know if you have any idea from this snippet. if you want more go this [link](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/), which is great article by **Bill Phillips**.